# After login into AWS userpool, the session expires immediately in Samsung device

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I am using AWS Cognito for login and sign up in one of my application. AWS Appsyc with dynamoDb for storing data. After login, I am not able to fetch the data from dynamoDb using appsync query in Samsung s6 device. The currentUser session always gives "Failed to authenticate user" error.

It works perfectly in all other devices.

Comment: Hi, are you able to give some more information such as the SDK version you are using, code sample, and a stacktrace? You may also open an issue on the official SDK repository https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/issues